# Create triggers on recently programmatically copied Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have this main Form that uses its responses to create several other Forms after it's been submitted, but I need that these Forms that were recently created to send emails on their submissions without needing to edit manually each of their individual scripts.

Is there anyway I could do this using only the code and events from the main Form that triggers the creation of all those other forms?

Answer (score 0):

To create triggers programmatically use Class [Trigger Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)

#### forForm(form)

Creates and returns a FormTriggerBuilder tied to the given form.

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
   .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();
```